# Is there any way to compare two slicers which have same column of a table In Power BI

Tags: powerbi

In my Power Bi report I have 2 slicer which will dynamically update the Stacked-chart

I have one table which have a column as City which has values as

1. Kolkata
2. Mumbai
3. Delhi
4. Goa

this column is used in 2 columns in the same report if the user selects a particular city from the slicer1 then values in Slicer will change and the selected city from slicer1 will not be shown in Slicer2

For example if user selects Kolkata in slicer1
then  Slicer2 will only have values

1. Mumbai
2. Delhi
3. Goa

I have tried a measure like this to achieve the same

`test = VAR selection =SELECTEDVALUE('Sheet1'[city]) VAR compare = SELECTEDVALUE('Sheet1'[city2]) return IF(selection = compare,"test")`

here I have duplicated the column city and used in the second slicer as I am using the single Sheet
but the issue occurs as I am only getting the selected value for the first value in the slicer for other it is coming as blank

Comment: can you add details to let people see what you have tried, seems your question is about powerbi slicers but without something for people to look at and correct the question becomes too general to be answerable without writing an article like this one https://data-flair.training/blogs/power-bi-slicer/ which you can already find outthere

Comment: T. Nielsen I have modified it do have a look

Comment: I think that looks like enough to get started in understanding where the problem. Very nice elaboration @Shashank